# How do you set the current month as the default option in a drop down list in yii?

Tags: php, date, yii, drop-down-menu

I want to create a form and want to set the current month(real time) as the default value on my drop down list. I have this code which selects 'Jan' as the default selection. How do I modify my code?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'READING_MONTH'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'READING_MONTH',
    array ('1' =>'Jan', '2'=>'Feb', '3' => 'Mar', '4'=>'Apr', '5' => 'May', '6'=>'Jun',
        '7' => 'Jul', '8' => 'Aug', '9' => 'Sep', '10' => 'Oct', '11'=> 'Nov', '12' => 'Dec'));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'READING_MONTH'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code :

```
<?php
    // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters
    // for more details about the parameter of date() function.
    $model->READING_MONTH = date('n');
    // see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1799
    // to know how Yii detect selected value.
    echo $form->dropDownList(
        $model,
        'READING_MONTH',
        array (
            '1'  => 'Jan',
            '2'  => 'Feb',
            '3'  => 'Mar',
            '4'  => 'Apr',
            '5'  => 'May',
            '6'  => 'Jun',
            '7'  => 'Jul',
            '8'  => 'Aug',
            '9'  => 'Sep',
            '10' => 'Oct',
            '11' => 'Nov',
            '12' => 'Dec'
        )
    );
?>
```